# Appending a row in csv file with python (PANDA)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

As the title suggests I am trying to add a row to an already existing csv file created in python using pandas with: `df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", index=False, header=True)`, and looking around the internet I found this method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=[f"{name}", f"{usr}", f"{passw}"])
df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", mode="a", header=False)
```

but when I look at the csv file nothing happens.
Am I doing something wrong?
I am going to include the entire function even though I don't think it matters that much

```
# Takes the user input and appends it to the csv file (this is where I have the problem)
def usr_input():
    name = input("Website name: ")
    usr = input("Email or username: ")
    passw = input("Password: ")

    df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=[f"{name}", f"{usr}", f"{passw}"])
    df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", mode="a", header=False)

    flag = input("Add another one? (y/n): ")
    if flag == "y":
        usr_input()
    else:
        quit()
```

This is where I create the csv file:

```
def init():
    if not os.path.isfile("dataframe.csv"):
        df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["Name", "Email / Username", "Password"])
        df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", index=False, header=True)
    else:
        usr_input()
```

Comment: Just a remark: using pandas only to add one line at the end of a csv file is close  to use a jackhammer to crush a mosquito... Not wrong but overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! I just needed to use the loc[] function:

```
data = [f"{name}", f"{usr}", f"{passw}"]
df.loc[len(df)] = data
df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", index=False)
```